# Regular expression that contains no aab-substring

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

I need to construct a regular expression that defines a language containing all words that contain no `aab-substring` and end in `bb`.

I'm not too sure if this is correct - `(a + (aaa)*)* b* bb` - I'm not sure on how to allow multiple `a`'s that are more than two `a`'s

Comment: Do you have letters other than `a` and `b`? Otherwise, as soon as you have seen `aa` you have lost -- you need to switch from `a`s to `b`s sooner or later, and that will give you the forbidden `aab`.

Comment: How about $b^*(ab^+)^*b$? (Note that you can never have two consecutive $a$'s, since they are either followed by a $b$ eventually, or the string ends in an $a$.

Comment: @Henning Makholm The universal set is `{ a b }` so just those two. @rogerl, can that regular expression produce `aaab`?

Comment: @rogerl: Unfortunately that also generates the string `b`, which fails to end with `bb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a word in the language must end with $bb$, any $a$ or string of $a$s in the word will eventually be followed by a $b$. This means that if the word contains $aa$, it will necessarily contain $aab$. Thus, we cannot allow the substring $aa$ at all. Clearly a word may start with any number of $b$s, so let’s try starting the regular expression with $b^*$. Then we can alternate non-empty strings of $b$s with single $a$s as often as we want: $b^*(ab^+)^*$.

Now we just need to make sure that we get $bb$ on the end. This is actually a little tricky: a word generated by $b^*(ab^+)^*$ can end in any number of $b$s, including none at all. One way to handle the problem is to separate the words of the language with no $a$s from those that contain at least one $a$. The first set is easy: it’s generated by $b^*bb$. The second is generated by $b^*(ab^+)^*ab^*bb$, where I’ve pulled the last $a$ out of the $(ab^+)^*$ repeating block so that I know where the last block of $b$s starts.

Now put it together:

$$b^*bb+b^*(ab^+)^*ab^*bb=\big(\lambda+b^*(ab^+)^*a\big)b^*bb$$

or, if you don’t want to stick to strict regular expressions,

$$\big(\lambda+b^*(abb^*)^*a\big)b^*bb\;.$$

(I use $\lambda$ for the empty word; you may be used to $\epsilon$ instead.)

**Added:** **Henning Makholm** points out in the comments below that there is another nice way to cover all of these cases, one that is very compact if you allow the $^+$ operator:

$$\big((a+\lambda)b\big)^+b=\big((a+\lambda)b\big)\big((a+\lambda)b\big)^*b$$

Comment: How about just $(a^?b)^+b$?

Comment: @Henning: What’s $a^?$? $a+\lambda$?

Comment: x @Brian: Yes, $E?$ abbreviates $(E\mid \lambda)$ -- I thought that was as common as $E^+$ for  for $EE^*$; good old unixy REs support both.

Comment: @Henning: I think that I might have seen it at some point, but it’s not nearly so familiar as $E^+$, perhaps because most of my exposure to REs has been in non-programming contexts. At any rate, it does appear that your suggestion works; I’ll add it to my answer.

Comment: Great explanation and answer, thank you both!

Comment: @SnakeEater: You're welcome!